# LXML: Replacing elements from string with namespaces

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How to replace a certain element with a string snippet using the same namespaces?

```
<!-- language: python -->
from lxml import etree

replacestring = '''<AP_PTO gml:id="DEAL123456789abc">
<new>This Element is new!</new>
</AP_PTO>'''


file = etree.parse("nasfile.xml")
root = file.getroot()
nsmap = root.nsmap.copy()
nsmap['adv'] = nsmap.pop(None)
nodes = root.xpath(".//adv:geaenderteObjekte/wfs:Transaction", namespaces=nsmap)
# Iterate object elements
for t in nodes[0]:
    for obj in t:
        oart = str(etree.QName(objekt.tag).localname)
        if oart == 'Filter':
            pass
        else:
            objid = (obj.xpath('@gml:id', namespaces=nsmap))[0][:16]
            if objid == 'DEAL123456789abc':
                t.replace(obj, etree.fromstring(replacestring))
                #nodes[0].remove(t)
```

I got the namespaces from my inputfile as nsmap:

```
{'adv': 'http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0',
 'asdkom': 'http://www.lverma.nrw.de/namespaces/kom-ok/1.1',
 'fc': 'http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/fc/6.0',
 'gco': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco',
 'gmd': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd',
 'gml': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2',
 'gsr': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr',
 'gss': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss',
 'gts': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts',
 'ogc': 'http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/ogc',
 'wfs': 'http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfs',
 'wfsext': 'http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/wfsext',
 'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
 'xs': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
```

If I remove the gml: Prefix from replacestring the loop works as expected. The string replaces the former element with the given ID. But with the prefix I got an: 
XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix gml for id on AP_PTO is not defined, line 2, column 34

How to tell lxml to use the namespaces defined in nsmap from the source file?

Answer (score 1):

Any XML that uses namespaces must declare those namespaces, it always needs to be self-contained.

So this:

```
replacestring = '''<AP_PTO gml:id="DEAL123456789abc">
<new>This Element is new!</new>
</AP_PTO>'''
```

needs to be like this:

```
replacestring = '''<AP_PTO gml:id="DEAL123456789abc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
<new>This Element is new!</new>
</AP_PTO>'''
```

The purpose of the `nsmap` is to let Python know about the namespaces your XML uses, not the other way around.

---

In fact, and that is why it is named "map", it lets you choose the prefixes you want to use in your XPath. It maps a namespace URI to a short handle. This:

```
obj.xpath('@foobar:id', namespaces=nsmap)
```

will work just fine if your nsmap defines `foobar` properly:

```
{'foobar': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2'}
```

It doesn't matter at all what prefixes are used in the XML. The prefix needs to resolve to the correct URI, respectively, and the URIs need to be equal. The prefixes themselves don't have to be equal.